# Custom Menu based off custom header

Tags: menus, page-template, custom-header

I'm using my Child of TwentyTwelve

Just for your knowledge, I have two sections to my one WordPress site... one is called pain, the other called anesthesia (It's a medical site for the curious).

I have created two menus: "pain-menu" and "anesthesia-menu"... of course, I would like each menu to be seen on its corresponding section. Currently, "pain-menu" is selected for the Primary Menu and is seen all across the site.

I'm using the Default page template for the Pain section.

I have also created a page template called... wait for it... "Anesthesia." I can currently select this template when creating new pages for the anesthesia section.

Even more, this Anesthesia page template calls its own header, called 'header-anesthesia'. No surprises there.

So, the question is- how do I hard-code the call for "anesthesia-menu" in the 'header-anesthesia'... or is this even possible?

Thanks for taking the time to attempt to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `'theme_location'` argument in `header-anesthesia.php`:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'anesthesia-menu'
    )
);
```

WordPress will look for a menu assigned to this location now and pick that instead of the default menu.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response, @toscho, I appreciate it. I think your suggestion is on the right path, but it didn't work correctly for me. 

When I applied your sample code to appropriate area within the header template, it actually combined both of the menus. 

My preview site: http://uni4painrx-preview.com/

Looking at my home page, you shouldn't see "welcome", "types" or "locations A"... those links belong in the anesthesia-menu. 

Perhaps I'm not understanding how the custom Menus work? It wouldn't be the first time I didn't' get it. : )